# Basic MVC: What does "modelItem =>" do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is a sample line of code that is often generated by Visual Studio in an MVC type of application:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
```

- I understand how razor works (the `@`)
- I understand Html is an object with static helper functions, like `DisplayFor()`
- I understand `item.LastName` as this loosely represents a row and column from data/model

...but what the heck is `modelItem =>`? Back in my day, `=>` used to be an operator that was evaluated to a Boolean value. What is this sorcery?

Comment: The notation is C#, not MVC specific. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx

Comment: Wow, I loved this question! :)

Answer (score 13):

What you are doing there is passing a lambda expression.  These are essentially the same as delegates, function pointers in C or functions in Javascript.  Youare basically telling Html DisplayFor "use this function to get the display item".  Your example should actually probably be:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.LastName)
```

Otherwise, you are trying to close "item" from an outer scope.  If this is what you are really trying to do, then modelItem is doing essentially nothing...

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I just saw `modelItem` in some scaffolded MVC code and I'd thought I'd just add to bunglesticks answer.

The piece of code in the question probably comes from a standard MVC scaffolded index view (where the model is an `IEnumerable<TModel>`) and has this surrounding it:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

}
```

The code is using this overload of DisplayFor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

Therefore the modelItem (as bunglestink said) is doing nothing (it's not used in the result). The `item.LastName` returns the actual LastName for that item in the IEnumerable and `DisplayFor` will generate the correct html for the datatype.

Comment: Thx for explaining `modelItem`, that always bothered me.